# parse number with spaces to float

Tags: javascript

I have the following string '1 234' and I would like to parse it to float.

I have tried varios of solutions but none of them works for me.

I have tried:

```
parseFloat('1 234'.trim())
parseFloat('1 234'.split(' ').join())
parseFloat('1 234'.replace(/ /g, ''))
```

Comment: What do you mean `IT DOES NOT WORK`. You get an error? What error? You get a value you weren't expecting? What value do you get, and what were you expecting? Something else? *What?*

Comment: What is the expected results?

Comment: Expected result would be 1234, but the result I am getting is 1

Comment: The second and fourth versions **do** work.

Comment: And you shouldn't be using `parseFloat()` anyway; use either the Number constructor or a unary `+` on the scrubbed string.

Comment: The worked versions are [here](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3z3yvkzbx) as mentioned by @Pointy.

Comment: Are you sure you have a space in there, not a different white space character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
> parseFloat('1 234'.replace(/\s/g,''))
1234
>
```

Comment: thank you! It works for me. I can accept your answer in 10 minutes (stackoverflow rule)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```js
parseFloat("1 234".replace(" ", "."))
```

Comment: 1234 and 1.234 are not the same. `.replace(" ", "")` is already provided in the question statement.

Comment: Yes, I thought he wanted it to look like 1.234, that's why I tried to replace the space with a dot.